# Cocoa frameworks roles

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, frameworks

I have some shared code I want to reuse in my Xcode projects. The easiest way is using a shared framework. I must make headers public in order to reuse the framework in my projects.

Now: since the framework must be copied inside final products, is there an automatic way to prevent public headers from being copied too? Of course I can do this manually, but an automated trick would be amazing   :)

Thank you

Comment: If all you are trying to do is "reuse" code than creating a custom .framework is definitely *not* the easiest way.

Comment: What would you suggest? A SCM repo?

Comment: Is this for personal consumption?  iOS or Mac OS X?  Able to support just Xcode 4 and newer or do you need to still support Xcode 3?

Comment: Personal use, MacOS X, Xcode 3.2.6

Comment: For that, probably just dragging the shared project into the primary project is the way to go. If you can move to Xcode 4, workspaces make this even easier. (Xcode 3 is deprecated, so no time like the present!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, you can do all that with frameworks. Frameworks can be installed system-wide, or inside the application package. If you haven't read it yet, it's in the docs : [Embedding a Private Framework in Your Application Bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002258-106880)

Basically, you're going to make two variants of your framework, one for developing client applications, one for embedding inside those applications. In Xcode you can :

- either setup two framework targets, and change the Header files' roles as wanted (public or private)
- or use the `PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH` build setting with different values in two build configurations. (Say, "Development" and "Deployment"). Your header files will end up in different locations this way.

I haven't done this for a long time, but I don't have particularly good memories of embedded frameworks. What type of code are you reusing exactly? Is this common, all-purpose code? Or is it a whole, coherent project?

If you're just trying to reuse generic code, you might be better off using a simple, old-school `.a` static library with a headers folder, or even better, a [static framework](http://blog.cloudmade.com/2010/05/10/iphone-static-framework/). (Which is just a static library inside a framework bundle)

Comment: Ok, I finally managed to do this: I keep all the framework's headers "private", so they don't get copied in final bundles. In those projects referring to that framework, I just import its headers by setting the headers search path (in the project settings) to the framework build folder.